# component unit testing in Glimmer

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, integration-testing, glimmer.js

For classic component unit tests, how would we migrate this to Glimmer? This component unit test is testing a local prop that is not exposed to the user.

```
const component = this.owner
  .factoryFor('component:some-component')
  .create({
    someModel: { foo: 'bar' }
  });

assert.equal(component.get('someLocalProp'), false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are indeed an anti-pattern!  Indeed, unit testing components is an anti-pattern in general: you're not actually [testing the interface](https://v4.chriskrycho.com/2019/test-the-interface.html) of the component that way. Here's what I mean by that: all interactions with the component, both as another developer invoking it and as a user interacting with it, happen via the template. "Unit" testing it like this does not represent how *either* the end user or the other developers who invoke it will be able to interact with it.

Most of the time, tests like this exist because a developer wanted to check the behavior of an internal method or getter. However, that's exactly the *opposite* of what we should do when testing. We *only* want to test the public contract: that's what allows us to actually do the work of refactoring: that is, changing the internal implementation *without* changing the public contract. Tests which rely on internal behavior are necessarily over-coupled and fragile. In the case of UI components, that means that "unit" tests like this are effectively *always* over-coupled and fragile.

For example, if a getter isn't visible in the template directly, who cares whether it computes a given value or not? We really only care about the *result* of the computation.

There's no directly-corresponding API for Glimmer components, partly for that reason. The right pattern here is to rewrite the component test into an integration test, which *does* allow you to test the actual interface of the component (or to remove it if it's not providing actual value).